# Data not posted on firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save new data in firebase under a node `President`. i have already set some rules on that node.

```
"President":{
  "$userId":{
    ".write": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid",
      ".read": " auth.uid != null"
  }
},
```

In my app

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

if(mFirebaseUser == null){

}else{
  String mUserId = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
  DatabaseReference vRef = mDatabase.getReference(MyFirebaseConstants.DATABASE_President);
  DatabaseReference newPresidentRef = vRef.child(mUserId).push();
  String presidentKey = newPresidentRef.getKey();

 President pres = new President()//POJO
  // other few setters

  pres.setId(visitorKey);
  newPresidentRef.setValue(pres).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
      MyLogger.d("failed to save "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
      MyLogger.d("succedded");
    }
  }).isSuccessful();
```

**my President pojo extends RealmObject and implements Parcelable**

However when i go to my firebase console, i can't see any data. `onSuccess()` is never called and `onFailure()` is never called.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had restricted background data on my device. therefore data was not posted to firebase.

I haven't yet found a better way to detect background data restriction on android device